# How to render Exception.Data dictionary the same way IncludeEventProperties does for event properties in NLog?

Tags: c#, json, exception, logging, nlog

Is it possible to get NLog using `JsonLayout` to write out the `Exception.Data` dictionary as actual JSON instead of just a single attribute serialized with its `toString`?

The closest I have been able to get is this:

```xml
<attribute name='data' layout='${exception:format=data}' />
```

which becomes

```json
    "exception": {
        "type": "System.IO.InvalidDataException",
        "message": "Invalid PERSON identifier: xyz",
        "data": "entity: PERSON;value: xyz",
        "stacktrace": "..."
    }
```

or this

```xml
<attribute name='exception' layout='${exception:format=@}'/>
```

which becomes

```json
"exception": "{\"Type\":\"System.IO.InvalidDataException\", \"Message\":\"Invalid PERSON identifier: xyz\", \"Data\":{\"entity\":\"PERSON\",\"value\":\"xyz\"}, \"TargetSite\":\"Void MoveNext()\", \"StackTrace\":\"...\", \"HResult\":-2146233087}"
```

Ideally I would like to see a layout configuration that yields:

```json
    "exception": {
        "type": "System.IO.InvalidDataException",
        "message": "Invalid PERSON identifier: xyz",
        "data": {
            "entity": "PERSON",
            "value": "xyz",
        }
        "stacktrace": "..."
    }
```

This configuration will output event properties the way I want:

```xml
<attribute name="properties" encode="false" >
  <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="10"/>
</attribute>
```

```json
    "properties": {
        "controllerName": "Person",
        "actionName": "Lookup"
    }
```

But I haven't found a valid configuration that does the same thing for `Exception.Data`.  Has anyone been able to accomplish this **without manually adding every possible dictionary key to the configuration as an attribute** using `${exceptiondata:item=entity}` etc?

Comment: What about `<attribute name='exception' layout='${exception:format=@}' encode="false" />` ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen That worked perfectly, thank you!  Care to submit it as an answer so I can mark it accordingly? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `format=@` then it will output in json-format, but then you have to use `encode="false"` to avoid encoding as string-property:

```xml
<attribute name="exception" layout="${exception:format=@}" encode="false" />
```

Notice that some exceptions are dangerous, where the data-dictionary enumerates an entire database. You can use `RegisterObjectTransformation` to override the transformation of those exceptions.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#transform-captured-properties